# SSIS Conditional split condition

Tags: sql, ssis

```
 !(((ISNULL(Phone))&&(ISNULL(WorkPhone))&&(ISNULL(OtherPhone)))&&(((ISNULL(Phone))||

((!ISNULL(Phone))&&(PhoneXPC==1)))&&(((ISNULL(WorkPhone))||((!ISNULL(WorkPhone))&&

(WorkPhoneXPC==1)))&&(((ISNULL(OtherPhone))||((!ISNULL(OtherPhone))&&(OtherPhoneXPC==1)))))
```

Is there any flaw in this condition can anyone help us ......
we are having 6 columns involved in this condition it contains three type of phone numbers and three bit `XPC columns` for respective phone numbers for each records.

We allow to put the null values for phone number columns, and its respective `XPC column` will also be null.

so if anyone of these XPC columns contains 0 then that person should be put in one file and if anyone of these XPC column does not contain 0 but can contain null should be put in another file.

i am using visualstudio 2005

thanks in advance

Comment: why are you adding ! in may places ???

Comment: Is this also your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428258/conditional-split-over-the-data-coming-from-oledb)?

Answer (score 2):

That compound conditional is nasty enough to make me want to use a Script Component instead:

[image: screenshot of suggested data flow]

The Script Component (here, SCR_DetermineTarget) is configured as a synchronous transformation which adds a `TargetId` column to the dataflow. The following conditional split logic becomes simply comparing `TargetId` to whatever values you choose. I chose to use 1 to indicate that all the XPC fields were zero and 2 to indicate that at least one XPC field was nonzero but that all the phone numbers were null.

The code below (in VB, since you specified VS 2005) sets the `TargetId` appropriately:

```vb
Public Overrides Sub MyInput_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As MyInputBuffer)
    Dim targetId As Integer
    targetId = 0

    If Row.PhoneXPC = 0 Or Row.WorkPhoneXPC = 0 Or Row.OtherPhoneXPC = 0 Then
        targetId = 1
    ElseIf Row.Phone_IsNull Or Row.WorkPhone_IsNull Or Row.OtherPhone_IsNull Then
        targetId = 2
    End If

    Row.TargetId = targetId
End Sub
```

If that logic **isn't** what you were looking for, it should be much easier to fix it in VB.NET than in the bowels of a conditional transform, just on the basis of readability alone.

Comment: Thank you Edmund Schweppe :-) This solution was very much helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this !!

```
{

(((ISNULL(Phone)=="TRUE")&&(ISNULL(WorkPhone)=="TRUE")&&(ISNULL(OtherPhone)=="TRUE"))&&

(((ISNULL(Phone)=="TRUE")||((!ISNULL(Phone)=="TRUE")&&(PhoneXPC==1)))&&

(((ISNULL(WorkPhone)=="TRUE")||((!ISNULL(WorkPhone)=="TRUE")&&(WorkPhoneXPC==1)))&&

(((ISNULL(OtherPhone)=="TRUE")||((ISNULL(OtherPhone)=="TRUE")&&(OtherPhoneXPC==1)))))


 }
```

Let me know if it works

Ashutosh Arya